# How to find the index of a object with maximum properties in an array of objects in Javascript

Tags: arrays, object, indexof

How to find the index of a object with maximum properties in an array of objects.

Let say I have a below array

```
    xyz = [
        {firstName: "John"}
        {firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe"}
        {firstName: "Mary", lastName: "Doe", age: "25", city: "newyork"}
        {firstname: "Jack", lastName: "sparrow", state: "NJ"}
    ]
```

I would like to get the result as  result = 2, where 2 is the index of the object in the array xyz with more properties

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify a language so I wrote this in ruby because it is easy to read even if you aren't familiar.  The idea is pretty much the same in all languages.

```
def max_properties_index(xyz)
  max_count = 0
  result_index = nil
  xyz.each_with_index do |element, index|
    if element.keys.length > max_count
      max_count = element.keys.length
      result_index = index
    end
  end
  return result_index
end

xyz[max_properties_index(xyz)]  # returns the object in the array at the index
```